# Laravel - Possible to detect if package is running from workbench or vendor?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, package

I am sure with some hacking I could find a way to do this but I am hoping there is an elegant solution. I need to be able to detect when my package is running from the workbench of if the package is installed and running as a 3rd party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method in your main package class to do the check, like this:

```
MyClass {

    protected function getPackageLocation()
    {
        // Check if the path to this file contains 'workbench'
        if (strpos(realpath(__FILE__), 'workbench') !== false) {
            return 'workbench';
        }

        // If not, it's in vendor folder
        return 'vendor';
    }

}
```

If you need to check it from outside your package, you can always make the function public.

To make it more reliable, you can check for `workbench/your_vendor/your_package/`in the conditional, or even make it dynamic with something like:

```
// untested: translate namespace to path format
$needle = 'workspace/' . strtolower(str_replace("_", "/", __NAMESPACE__));

if (strpos(realpath(__FILE__), $needle) !== false) {
    ...
```

Comment: interesting. I guess it is somewhat a hack (in other words, not a method baked into the framework) however I don't see the directory name "vendor" changing any time soon so it is probably reliable enough. Thanks.

Comment: Well, there's no official method for this because your package should do the same no matter in which of these two folders it's located. Perhaps you want to make a new question with the real problem behind this one.

Comment: Manuel, FYI -- strpos() has the opposite param order than what you posted: http://www.php.net/function.strpos

Comment: Oops, that's what you get when you write code without testing it. Updated!